# iphone app run in the simulator but not on the device

Tags: iphone, gcc, ios-simulator, device

I am trying to run the Facebook DemoApp on my iphone and I get the following errors
(it works without errors on the simulator)

Please help me

```
*****************************
Build DemoApp of project DemoApp with configuration Debug

Ld build/DemoApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/DemoApp.build/Objects-normal/armv6/DemoApp normal armv6
cd /Users/aumidwilliams/Downloads/facebook-facebook-ios-sdk-57818a0/sample/DemoApp
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.0
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch armv6 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.0.sdk -L/Users/aumidwilliams/Downloads/facebook-facebook-ios-sdk-57818a0/sample/DemoApp/build/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/aumidwilliams/Downloads/facebook-facebook-ios-sdk-57818a0/sample/DemoApp/build/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/aumidwilliams/Downloads/facebook-facebook-ios-sdk-57818a0/sample/DemoApp/build/DemoApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/DemoApp.build/Objects-normal/armv6/DemoApp.LinkFileList -dead_strip -fopenmp -miphoneos-version-min=4.0 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/aumidwilliams/Downloads/facebook-facebook-ios-sdk-57818a0/sample/DemoApp/build/DemoApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/DemoApp.build/Objects-normal/armv6/DemoApp

arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: libgomp.spec: No such file or directory
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Ld build/DemoApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/DemoApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/DemoApp normal armv7
cd /Users/aumidwilliams/Downloads/facebook-facebook-ios-sdk-57818a0/sample/DemoApp
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.0
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch armv7 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.0.sdk -L/Users/aumidwilliams/Downloads/facebook-facebook-ios-sdk-57818a0/sample/DemoApp/build/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/aumidwilliams/Downloads/facebook-facebook-ios-sdk-57818a0/sample/DemoApp/build/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/aumidwilliams/Downloads/facebook-facebook-ios-sdk-57818a0/sample/DemoApp/build/DemoApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/DemoApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/DemoApp.LinkFileList -dead_strip -fopenmp -miphoneos-version-min=4.0 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/aumidwilliams/Downloads/facebook-facebook-ios-sdk-57818a0/sample/DemoApp/build/DemoApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/DemoApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/DemoApp

arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: libgomp.spec: No such file or directory
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 12):

Unchecking "Enable OpenMP Support" in Project -> Edit Project Settings -> Build fixed the problem for me.